# Retrieve Data from Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 1 activity which will host 2 fragments. Using an HttpGet request, I will retrieve a list of objects that will be put into a listview (one of the fragments). Would it be better design to put this request inside the activity's onCreate method? Or, would it be better inside the fragment's onCreate method?

### Activity

```
onCreate() {
// call method to retrieve data (httpget request)
// parse json data to a list of objects
// implement the parcelable interface to pass data to the fragment through a bundle
}
```

Or

### Fragment

```
onCreate() {
// call method to retrieve data (httpget request)
// parse json data to a list of objects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. In most cases fragment should contain this `HttpGet` logic because it should be a separate module that you can use across different activities. `Activity` is just a container for fragments that controls the lifecycle and interaction between them.